# 'webpack_loader' is not a registered tag library

Tags: python, django, reactjs, webpack, django-webpack-loader

I am starting to learn some react, and trying to learn how to combine ReactJS and Django. I am currently following the proposed tutorial [here](http://v1k45.com/blog/modern-django-part-1-setting-up-django-and-react/)

After setting up the django urls, and installing `django-webpack-loader`, I am stuck with the following error when running the django server:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

'webpack_loader' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

My current `index.html` is as follows:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Ponynote</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
      {% render_bundle 'main' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I already tried going on, and setting up the rest, but nothing seems to work. The error I am getting is different from the one in the tutorial and both in the github page of `django-webpack-loader` package and here I can't see any problem like this. The solutions for similar errors I found here did not solve my problems, so I am not sure what or where the error is lying.

I tried:

- Literally copy-pasting the tutorial code
- remaking the entire project
- several solutions like creating a custom tag
- checking if the react(webpack) server is running

Info:

```
Django version 2.0.5
django-webpack-loader==0.6.0
Python version 3.6.5
Running on Ubuntu x64 18.04 LTS
```

Thanks for any help, and sorry if this is a stupid, simple to solve mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add `webpack_loader` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` as described in the tutorial:

> Then in the project settings.py (`ponynote.settings`) add `webpack_loader` in `INSTALLED_APPS` list and add the following [...]`